# Adding different sprites dynamically

Tags: android, andengine, sprite

I'm working on a simple game, just to figure out different AndEngine options.

I'm stuck on a seemingly simple matter.

I have 10 .png images (48 x 60 pixels) in (assets/gfx and / or (res/drawable).
Each of the images has a sound associated with it (res/raw).

I need to add all these as sprites, in a random order to my scene. A click on sprite plays the associated sound (if I click on banana.png, it plays the banana sound).

Normally I would have a list of my objects and use a for loop to run through all of them and add something like ImageView for each, but I have no idea how to handle the TextureAtlas and TextureRegion to make it work in SimpleBaseGameActivity.

Comment: first of you have to refer this example-(How to add sprine in Scene)
http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/SpriteExample.java

Comment: I've already gone through most of AndEngine examples and made a test app where I  shoot a single object around the screen. But now I need to add ten sprites, all with different textures and they need to aligned at the top of the screen, in random order.

Comment: you have which version use GLES1 or GLES2 ?

Comment: Use Buildable texture atlas.It will manage your dynamic texture automatically.Make all texture regions with this Texture itself.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working yesterday with Buildable Texture Atlas.